# How to do query correctly in this case?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In the database, there are two users,

```
// User1

    {ABC: [{aa:"11", bb:"11"}, {aa:"22", bb:"22"}]}

// User2

    {ABC: [{aa:"11", bb:"22"}, {aa:"33", bb:"44"}]}
```

I want to get users whose `aa = 11`, and `bb = 22` at the same time in one element of the array. So I only want to get User2 here.

```
let users = Meteor.users.find({$and: [{'ABC.aa': "11"}, {'ABC.bb': "22"}]});
```

But now I got both users using this query. How can I write the query correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$elemMatch` to match an entire element:

```
let users = Meteor.users.find({ ABC: { $elemMatch: { aa: "11", bb: "22" }}});
```